# How to find heading from an Android phone using quaternions?

Tags: android, quaternions, heading, sensor-fusion

I used [this](http://www.thousand-thoughts.com/2012/03/android-sensor-fusion-tutorial/) sensor fusion tutorial to fuse the gyro, accelerometer and magnetic compass values. I need to get the heading for the device from these values, I'm sorry if my question is vague but I cannot figure out how to get the heading for the device even with these values.

Comment: what do you mean by Heading for the device?

Comment: the orientation of the device with respect to the initial position